# JSON transformation using JOLT for Multiple arrays

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

I am new new to JSON. I have Input JSON which includes two arrays. 1st one (main results) contains two vendor and other one (BankDetailSet ->results) has vendor bank details (Key and Account ).i-e vendor can have multiple accounts. In put each vendor has two accounts. I am trying with Jolt, in output, I am able to get Vendor info and bank (bsb and account_number). The issue is corresponding vendor bank (bsb and account_number ) have been populated with wrong details.

1. In Input
   1st vendor **(Chigo PvtLimited")** has **BankKey** **(9877988787 & 89797879798)**
   while second one **(UFCDD  Pvt Limited)** has **BankKey** **(652588887 & 294454545)**
2. In Out Put 1st vendor **(Chigo PvtLimited")** has **bsb** (9877988787 & **652588887)**
   while second one **(UFCDD  Pvt Limited)** has **bsb**  (89797879798 & **294454545)**

The question is why Bankey values have been interchanged in output (bsb). I have pasted below the current and expected output

The **Input** is :

```json
{
  "d": {
    "results": [
      {
        "__metadata": {
          "type": "Core vendor.Vendor"
        },
        "VendorNumber": "7779898",
        "VendorName": "Chigo PvtLimited",
        "BankDetailSet": {
          "results": [
            {
              "__metadata": {
                "type": "UFCDR Pvt Limited"
              },
              "BankKey": "9877988787",
              "BankAccount": "987788798778879"
            },
            {
              "__metadata": {
                "type": "UFCDR Pvt Limited"
              },
              "BankKey": "89797879798",
              "BankAccount": "564654456456465"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "__metadata": {
          "type": "Alpha vendor.Vendor"
        },
        "VendorNumber": "987545",
        "VendorName": "UFCDD  Pvt Limited",
        "BankDetailSet": {
          "results": [
            {
              "__metadata": {
                "type": "UFCDD.BankDetail"
              },
              "BankKey": "652588887",
              "BankAccount": "66887454"
            },
            {
              "__metadata": {
                "type": "UFCDR Pvt Limited"
              },
              "BankKey": "294454545",
              "BankAccount": "4578777"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

the **Spec** I've tried :

```json
  [
    {
      "operation": "shift",
      "spec": {
        "d": {
          "results": {
            "*": {
              "VendorNumber": "vendors.[&1].name",
              "VendorName": "vendors.[&1].VendorName",
              "BankDetailSet": {
                "results": {
                  "*": {
                    "BankKey": "vendors[&1].Bank[&4].bsb",
                    "BankAccount": "vendors[&1].Bank[&4].account_number"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

The **Current Output**

```json
{
  "vendors": [{
    "name": "7779898",
    "VendorName": "Chigo PvtLimited",
    "Bank": [{
      "bsb": "9877988787",
      "account_number": "987788798778879"
    }, {
      "bsb": "652588887",
      "account_number": "66887454"
    }]
  }, {
    "Bank": [{
      "bsb": "89797879798",
      "account_number": "564654456456465"
    }, {
      "bsb": "294454545",
      "account_number": "4578777"
    }],
    "name": "987545",
    "VendorName": "UFCDD  Pvt Limited"
  }]
}
```

and the **Expected Output**

```json
    {
      "vendors": [
        {
          "name": "7779898",
          "VendorName": "Chigo PvtLimited",
          "Bank": [
            {
              "bsb": "9877988787",
              "account_number": "987788798778879"
            },
            {
              "bsb": "89797879798",
              "account_number": "564654456456465"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "987545",
          "VendorName": "UFCDD  Pvt Limited",
          "Bank": [
            {
              "bsb": "652588887",
              "account_number": "66887454"
            },
            {
              "bsb": "294454545",
              "account_number": "4578777"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can collect the elements `"VendorNumber"`, `"VendorName"` and the object with key name `"BankDetailSet"` under common object notation, then set the relative positioning wildcards such as `[&1]`, `[&4]` to meet at the same level of indexes of the outermost `"results"` array such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "d": {
        "results": {
          "*": {
            "VendorNu*": "vendors[&1].name",
            "VendorNa*": "vendors[&1].&",
            "Bank*": {
              "results": {
                "*": {
                  "Bank*": "vendors[&1].Bank[&4].&(0,1)"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the demo on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is
[image]

Edit : What you need within the last comments is just reverse of the previous one, eg. use

```
"Bank*": "vendors[&4].Bank[&1].&(0,1)"
```

instead of

```
"Bank*": "vendors[&1].Bank[&4].&(0,1)"
```

or literally use (as in your case)

```
"BankKey": "vendors[&4].Bank[&1].bsb",
"BankAccount": "vendors[&4].Bank[&1].account_number"
```

such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "d": {
        "results": {
          "*": {
            "VendorNu*": "vendors[&1].name",
            "VendorNa*": "vendors[&1].&",
            "Bank*": {
              "results": {
                "*": {
                  "BankKey": "vendors[&4].Bank[&1].bsb",
                  "BankAccount": "vendors[&4].Bank[&1].account_number"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** is

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for quick response. One more thing is i want to change the keys name as per below expected result.

Comment: Thank you so much for quick response. Output is as per expected.

Comment: Hi @AtharIqbal , you're welcome. Then just replace the line `"Bank*": "vendors[&1].Bank[&4].&(0,1)"` with two lines : `"BankK*": "vendors[&1].Bank[&4].bsb",
                  "BankA*": "vendors[&1].Bank[&4].account_number"`

Comment: Were you able to check the last case out @AtharIqbal ?

Comment: @ Barbaros Özhan. Yes, I did it and notice big issue. In Input
1st vendor BankKey are 9877988787 & 89797879798 
while 2nd vendor has 652588887 & 294454545.  while in out put,
1st Bank bsb are  9877988787 & 652588887 and 
2nd has  89797879798 & 294454545. We can see values are interchanged.  So I tried with 10 vendors and can see each Bank  has 10  bsb and account_number array instead of 2.   So it's basically populating 1st bankey from each vendor into 1st bank bsb.  in 2nd bank its populating 2nd bankey of each vendor and so on.  

What's it's resolution.

Comment: Hi @AtharIqbal , Can you edit the question to describe what extra you need ?

Comment: Hi @Barbaros Özhan I have edited the question. The Bankkey values from input  have been interchanged  in out put attribute (bsb) .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245360/discussion-between-athar-iqbal-and-barbaros-ozhan).

Comment: Well, just edited as desired @AtharIqbal when I'm available.

Comment: I already edited as you desired I meant @AtharIqbal , can you check it?

Answer (score 1):

@ Barbaros Özhan,   Thank you so much, below one is producing the required result..

[
{
"operation": "shift",

```
"spec": {

  "d": {

    "results": {


      "*": {
        "VendorNu*": "vendors[&1].name",
        "VendorNa*": "vendors[&1].&",
        "Bank*": {
          "results": {
            "*": {
              "BankKey": "vendors[&4].Bank[&1].bsb",
              "BankAccount": "vendors[&4].Bank[&1].account_number"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}
]